# automatice bash command for multiple files

Tags: bash

I have a directory with multiple files

```
file1_1.txt
file1_2.txt
file2_1.txt
file2_2.txt
...
```

And I need to run a command structured like this

```
command [args] file1 file2
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to call the command just one time on all the files, instead of having to call It each time on each pair of files.

Comment: `I need to run a command structured like this` `to call the command just one time on all the file` it wouldn't be "like this", it would have more files then. If you want to call "like this", than there are two files there. And it depends on the command, if the command supports more files as arguments or not. What command is it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) and [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html), with [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html), since the order appears meaningful in your case:

```
find . -name 'file?_?.txt' | sort | xargs -n2 command [args]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `command` can take multiple pairs of files on the command line then it should be sufficient to run

```
command ... *_[12].txt
```

The files in expanded glob patterns (such as `*_[12].txt`) are automatically sorted so the files will be paired correctly.

If the `command` can only take one pair of files then it will need to be run multiple times to process all of the files.  One way to do this automatically is:

```
for file1 in *_1.txt; do
    file2=${file1%_1.txt}_2.txt
    [[ -f $file2 ]] && echo command "$file1" "$file2"
done
```

- You'll need to replace `echo command` with the correct command name and arguments.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${file1%_1.txt}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd (){
    readarray -d "  " arr <<<"$@"
    for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2))
    do
        n=$(($i+1))
        firstFile="${arr[$i]}"
        secondFile="${arr[$n]}"
        echo "pair --  ${firstFile} ${secondFile}"
    done
}

cmd file*_[12].txt

pair --  file1_1.txt  file1_2.txt 
pair --  file2_1.txt  file2_2.txt
```